# Limit whitespace stretch in justified HTML paragraphs

Tags: html, justify

I have some HTML documents generated by Sphinx.  Sphinx justifies the body text and sets it in a `div` of width 50em.  I can, of course, edit the generated CSS/HTML.  The text has some inline equations, in the form of pre-rendered images, that are about 50% as wide as the body text when viewed in my browser.  The combination of justified text and wide, unbreakable inline images sometimes produces large, ugly spaces between words.

Is there a way to use justified text while reducing the amount of space stretch?  For example, can the space width be constrained to some maximum value, and lines aligned to the left if they're underfull after stretching spaces?

**edit with example:**

Bad spacing happens when there is a short line of text before a wide image.  Here is a bit of generated HTML source.  The alt-tags contain TeX source of the formulas, so you can get an idea of how big these formulas are in comparison to a single word.

```
<p>Suppose that we want to sort a list of pairs, using the pair's first member as the key.
Given the list
<img class="math" src="math001.png" alt="[\pair 13,\pair 19,\pair 36,\pair 24,\pair 38]"/>,
we want a list of pairs starting with 1, a list of pairs starting with 2, and so forth.
The sorted list would be
<img class="math" src="math002.png" alt="[\,[\pair 13,\pair 19], [\pair 24], [\pair 36,\pair 38],[]\,]"/>.
More text follows.</p>
```

The last formula is a bit too wide to fit at the end of a line, so it's moved to the next line, resulting in very loose interword spacing.

```
Suppose that we want to sort a list of pairs, using the pair's first member
as the key.   Given the list [<1,3>, <1,9>, <2,4>, <3,6>, <3,8>], we want a
list of pairs  starting with 1,  a list  of pairs starting  with 2,  and so
forth.           The         sorted          list         would          be <-- This line!
[[<1,3>, <1,9>], [<2,4>], [<3,6>, <3,8>], []].  More text follows.
```

I would prefer to see something like the following.  I'm open to other suggestions.

```
Suppose that we want to sort a list of pairs, using the pair's first member
as the key.   Given the list [<1,3>, <1,9>, <2,4>, <3,6>, <3,8>], we want a
list of pairs  starting with 1,  a list  of pairs starting  with 2,  and so
forth.    The   sorted   list   would   be
[[<1,3>, <1,9>], [<2,4>], [<3,6>, <3,8>], []].  More text follows.
```

Comment: Please post some sample generated code that illustrates the issue. In general, the ways to control justification are rather limited in CSS, and I don’t think underfull lines can be produced. But depending on the content, hyphenation might help.